# load_child_theme_textdomain doesn't work in function.php

Tags: localization, textdomain

I have a child theme which is not localized. So I added this in function.php

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
function my_child_theme_setup() {
    load_child_theme_textdomain( 'mytheme', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
```

It doesn't work. I searched for hours and I read somebody advised putting this to the top of header.php

```
load_child_theme_textdomain( 'mytheme', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
```

Suddenly it started working.

The problem is solved but I'm still curious why the legal way didn't work. Any of you have an explanation?

Comment: I'm also confused about this action. In the child theme, do you then use the parent theme's text domain for l18n?

Comment: @Jay yes. You have to use main theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, mind your language please. If there are swear words in your code, please remove it before you post your code.

OK, to get to your question, there is nothing wrong with your code. It looks sound. Which parent theme are you using?

> I have a child theme which is not localized

You should have a look at how your strings are localized. You should also have to look at your naming of your language files. Go and have a look at the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers). Always remember, use the codex as reference. You can also go and have a look at this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-localize-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-22779) to get some insight.

Apart from that you should be good to go

**EDIT**

I would like to keep the first part of this answer as reference for others. Your question had me puzzled, and then it hit me like lightning, I also missed the most obvious mistake, your template is named wrongly.

There is a huge difference between `function.php` and `functions.php`. Wordpress automatically knows and uses `functions.php` as the main functions template in a theme. This template need not be called. On the other hand, function.php is just a template with no hierarchy. This template must be called in some way in your theme so that wordpress will know when and how to use that template.

So, on your question, just rename your `function.php` to `functions.php`

Comment: Sorry for swear in the code. And you are right about function.php and functions.php